# MaxMessageSizeExceededException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, weblogic

We are doing a EJB call as below which is returning us the MaxMessageSizeExceededException.

Java Code to Call the EJB -

```
Properties env = new Properties(); 
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory"); 
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://xxxxxx.xxxx.xxx.com:4444"); 
InitialContext context; 
try { 
    context = new InitialContext(env); 
    Home hb =  context.lookup("lookupname"); 
    Service service = hb.create(); 
    Request request = new Request(); 
    service.getAPI(request); 
}
```

Error Details -

```
<Error> <Socket> <BEA-000403> <IOException occurred on socket: Socket[addr=XXXX.xxx.xxx.com/xxx.x.xxx.xxx,port=xxxx,localport=xxxxx]
weblogic.socket.MaxMessageSizeExceededException: Incoming message of size: '10000080' bytes exceeds the configured maximum of: '10000000' bytes for protocol: 't3'.
weblogic.socket.MaxMessageSizeExceededException: Incoming message of size: '10000080' bytes exceeds the configured maximum of: '10000000' bytes for protocol: 't3'
```

On the Weblogic where the service is deployed they have updated the configs to 30MB,Do we have to do any changes in our client side to increase the incoming size of the response. Any JVM level changes.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try  setting the value programatically in your java code e.g:

```
System.setProperty("weblogic.MaxMessageSize", "300000000");
```

You can also set the value in your **JAVA_OPTIONS** `-Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize=300000000`

Source: https://blogs.oracle.com/LuzMestre/entry/how_to_fix_weblogic_socket

Comment: Yeah this System.setProperty("weblogic.MaxMessageSize", "300000000"); worked. Thank you !!